# How to write a function that returns the elements on odd positions in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

I can get it to return the odd index of number if I just run a for loop but when I'm trying to turn it into a function it't not returning anything?

```js
 
    function oddArrayIndex( arrayName, emptyIndex ) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arrayName.length; i += 2) {
        emptyIndex.push(arrayName[i]);
        }
    }
    var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    var oddIndex = [];
    oddArrayIndex(arr, oddIndex);
```

Comment: `oddArrayIndex` doesn't have a `return` statement, so what do you expect it to return? You are adding all values to the second argument, so after you called `oddArrayIndex`, `oddIndex` will hold the values. It's an unusual design decision but it works. Have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html if you are new to functions.

Comment: after the for loop you need to return the new array manually with return statement

Comment: You're mutating the array inside the function. Instead, create a new array inside the function then return that.

Comment: your code is working fine, the result is in `oddIndex`.

Comment: Rookie mistake. thanks!

Comment: Add         console.log(oddIndex); to the snippet I made - then delete the question. The code works

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the array returning an array with only odd values:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.filter(function(el, ind){
  return ind % 2 === 0;
}));
```

Comment: please do not answer working questions, close the question instead.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am really sorry I didn't know this rule. Will do next times